# Broadcast receiver IntentReceiverLeaked

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I am trying to download a file and after download want to update it in the database, but in my intent the service broadcast receiver is creating this issue:

```
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.dev.newtermain.services.intent_service.DownloadService has leaked IntentReceiver com.dev.newtermain.services.intent_service.DownloadService$DownloadCompleteReceiver@d4fdde9 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:731)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1179)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1159)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1153)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
    at com.dev.newtermain.services.intent_service.DownloadService.onStartCommand(DownloadService.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3228)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Here is my intent service code:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
 public DownloadService() {
    super("Download Service");
}

Long downloadId;
private DownloadManager downloadManager;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    completeReceiver = new DownloadCompleteReceiver();
}

@Override public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    onHandleIntent(intent);
    this.intent = intent;
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String key = intent.getStringExtra(DOWNLOAD_KEY);
    messageId = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_ID);
    mReactionId = intent.getStringExtra(REACTION_ID);
    int messageType = intent.getIntExtra(MESSAGE_TYPE, 3);
    initDownload(key, messageType);
}

private void initDownload(String key, int messageType) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", SharedPref.User.getToken());

    // In order for this if to run, you must use the Android 3.2 to
    // compile your app
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName);

    // Get download service and enqueue file
    downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    Logs.e("file download", "downloading begin");
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    this.registerReceiver(completeReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public class DownloadCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public DownloadCompleteReceiver() {
    }

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logs.e("file download", "broadcast received");
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId);
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
            int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            switch (status) {
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                    Logs.e("file download", "download successful");
                    updateDb(fileName, messageId, Id);
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                    Logs.e("file download", "download Fail");
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                    Logs.e("file download", "STATUS_PENDING");
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                    Logs.e("file download", "STATUS_RUNNING");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override public void onDestroy() {
    Logs.e("file download", "stopping service");
    this.unregisterReceiver(completeReceiver);
    downloadManager.remove(downloadId);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

As the documentation of the broadcast receiver suggests, I am unregistering the broadcast receiver, but I am not getting why I am getting this issue.

**EDIT**

I Applied all suggest answers the new Problem is If I add a broadcast receiver it will give success response but not saving file but when I remove the broadcast receiver file download successfully

Comment: After removing this line downloadManager.remove(downloadId) everything working fine because it removes the downloaded file anybody have the idea how I can remove the download notification of download manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your code with changing the position of your broadcast unregister function

```
@Override public void onDestroy() {
    downloadManager.remove(downloadId);
    this.unregisterReceiver(completeReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dhaval I already try it didn't send any exception but the issue is if I remove the broadcast receiver file is saving properly and when I add broadcast receiver not getting any file just success response

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The reason you are facing this issue is because `IntentService` runs to completion before the download is completed and your `DownloadCompleteReceiver` is still registered.

`downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);` doesn't download in a synchronous manner. As a result the `IntentService` runs to completion.

**Solution Approach**

If it's mandatory for you to have the status received, you can start a ForegroundService instead of `IntentService` and then register the receiver. In `onDestory()` of your Service, unregister the receiver.

Comment: hi @Sagar thanks for the quick reply in the foreground service there is no exception but the file is not downloading properly and it always says download successful

Comment: @VirendraVarma you are just listening to the response from DownloadManager right? May be the issue is really with your file or server. The successful response is from DownloadManager.